# '<=' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'QuerySet'

Tags: python, django

I want to make a substraction between total (its in model.py) and account balance. So here I have
Order Model.py :

```
class Order(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="product")
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateField(datetime.datetime.today, null=True)
    status = models.ForeignKey(
        Status, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    payment_method = models.ForeignKey(
        PaymentMethod, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    total = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.total = self.quantity * self.price
        return super().save(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

In this model I have total field so in views.py:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        total = Order.objects.filter().only('total')
        print(total)
        balance = request.session['customer']['coin']
        print(balance)
        if balance <= total:
            balance = balance - total
            print(balance)
            # Customer.objects.filter(id = request.session['customer']['id']).update(coin=balance)
            customer = Customer.objects.get(
                id=request.session['customer']['id'])
            customer.coin = balance
            customer.save()
            request.session['customer']['coin'] = balance

            return HttpResponse("Remaining balance: " + str(balance))

        return HttpResponse("Insufficient Balance")
```

I tried to fetch total field and subtract with balance but its not working and I am getting this error.

Another thing is i want to assign total field in a variable after this i want to substract with balance which i showed in views.py

Please save me

Comment: `balance` is a `float`, but `total` is a `QuerySet` of `Order`s...

Comment: Yes but i want to substract an orders total with the balance how can i achieve this ?? @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
total = Order.objects.filter().only('total')
```

will generate a *`QuerySet`* of `Order`s, by using `.only('total')`, you will only select the values for `.total` and fetch the oter ones later, if necessary, but even if you would use `.values(…)` it would still be a `QuerySet` (so a *collection*) of values, not a `float`, and thus comparing is not possible.

You can for example sum these up with [**`.aggregate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#aggregate):

```
from django.db.models import Sum

total = Order.objects.filter().aggregate(
    sum_total=Sum('total')
)['sum_total'] or 0
```

but you likely need to do some `.filter(…)`ing, otherwise you will retrieve the sum of *all* `Order`s in the database.

Comment: If i make my coin fiild float to integer will i be able to do what i want ??